# SubPixel corner refinement not leading to realistic results

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, corner-detection

I want to detect corners of a binary rectangle on a sub-pixel level. I labeled the corner points myself as an initial value. Now, getting the subPixel-corner should be a standard-task, however I do not get stable realistic results with the scikit-image algorithm "corner_subpix".

This is the image I want to get the subPixel corner points from (obviously top, left, right and bottom corner)

[image: enter original Image]

I tried several window-sizes, but none appears to be working. it appears that there is an offset in the calculated subpix corners that gets bigger the more I increase the window Size. Does someone know why this happens? This looks like such a standard task to me and it's also very close to the example scikit provides. (See Additional Info below)
TBH I think the scikit image documentation for this feature is very thin.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from skimage.feature import corner_subpix

pathToTheImage = r'...\foo'
img = cv2.imread(pathToTheImage)

grayscale = img[:,:,1]

coords = np.array([[119., 653.],
                   [188., 584.],
                   [186., 724.],
                   [255., 656.]])

coords_subpix = corner_subpix(grayscale, coords, window_size=3)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.imshow(grayscale, cmap = 'gray')
ax.scatter(coords[:,1], coords[:,0], 
           color = 'blue', label = 'original cornerpoints')
ax.scatter(coords_subpix[:,1], coords_subpix[:,0], 
           color = 'red', label = 'refined cornerpoints')
ax.legend()
```

[image: Found SubPixel Corner Points]

You can try it yourself, the code should be working once you fix the path.

Additional Information is here: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_corner.html

Comment: Do you still see the issue? I've fired up a fresh venv and I don't see such a huge discrepancy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSCWx.png .

Comment: i did not manage to get good results and stopped using this approach completely. The resolution you provided looks interesting however, and i will check it out in the upcoming days. what was the scikit-version you used?

Comment: scikit-image==0.17.2